# Site runs slow both in debug mode and after deploying to server, but is faster after clicking "stop debugging"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio-2015, debug-mode

I've got an asp.net application, it is running very slow when debugging. I know this is common, but even when it's deployed it is running slow. I'm talking 7-10 second delays to post a page in some cases.

If I run it in debug mode and click "stop debugging" in visual studio, I can still run through the app. It is WAY faster here, and everything is still being saved to the database and everything. Why is it so much faster here, and how can I make my deployed site run this fast?

**Summary**: What can cause my deployed site to run so slow (equally as slow as debug mode), but when I stop the debugger and mess with my local version while it's still brought up in the browser, it is WAY faster than both debug mode and my deployed site.

Comment: Deployed to where? Do you have Fusion logging enabled, for example? Anyway there's no single cause for this, start profiling. Glimpse could help here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps using **BrowserLink**, maybe without even knowing it? It is a technology where the website is constantly kept up-to-date with e.g. CSS changes while debugging is active. But it can also make things very, very slow.

To disable, add this line to `<appSettings>` in Web.Config:

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

References:

- http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Comment: This is a great answer to the question _"How do I disable BrowserLink"_, but I would start with the comment _"Are you perhaps using BrowserLink, maybe without even knowing it?"_ first.

Comment: It doesn't appear that it's using BrowserLink. I added that line and it didn't seem to do anything. My mind would have exploded if that would have worked. Thanks for the possible fix though.